# Operators in c++ : how to assign variable value from inside object to int variable using operators in c++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, type-conversion, operator-overloading

i am new to c++ , in case i have an object Obj , which has int variable ,
like Obj.var , how can i assign that value to another int using '=' operator ?

note: i have already poorly implemented code that someone else wrote which i would like to use without changing it , when Obj is generic , but it was used only for int

example below :

```
class Obj

{

public:

    int var ; 
};
```

---

```
int variable;

variable = Obj;
```

i would expect this to happen :

```
variable = Obj.var
```

Comment: What's stopping you from simply writing `variable = Obj.var;` ? It's way clearer than having voodoo happen behind the scenes to "unpack" an object.

Comment: `variable = Obj` ?? `Obj` is a class not an instance... make it `Obj obj;` and `int variable = obj.var;`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about guessing how the language works instead of consulting a reference

Comment: The magic word here is [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator). But I agree with @StoryTeller that wanting to use this is generally dubious. What's the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: nice question , its because i have already poorly implemented code that someone else wrote which i would like to use without changing it , when Obj is generic , but it was used only for int @StoryTeller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you can include in the class defintion a conversion operator.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

class Obj
{
public:
    operator int() const { return var; }
    int var ; 
};


int main()
{
    Obj obj = { 10 };

    int variable = obj;

    std::cout << "variable = " << variable << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
variable = 10
```

Or the operator can be defined also like

```
operator const int &() const { return var; }
```

Comment: yes it seems like it , thanks for the fast reply ! , i will try it out